# How to Store multiple fiori applications in single or multiple git repository

Tags: git, sap-fiori, sap-web-ide

I'm trying to develop 5-6 fiori applications and all these applications are related to one another in some way or the other, i.e. navigation is supported between one application to other application(s).

I'm using git tools integrated in the web ide. The repositories are hosted at git.hana.ondemand.com

i'm not able to figure out how to store these applications in git. i know there are a lot of blogs related to use of git with a single project but i couldn't find anything that provides some information about using multiple projects with git.

Is there a way possible to store them in one git repository or do i need multiple repositories for each application.

If more developers are working on these apps then what implications will be there during clone, pull or push and merge in case of using one repository or multiple repositories if and when its possible.

Answer (score 0):

The upside of all related apps being in a single repository: it's easy.

The downside: the history of the apps is inextricably linked. It's various degrees of tricky to only clone one of them, or to have different apps at different branches, or different points in history.

To solve part-of-the-project-but-actually-independent issue, git supports subtrees and submodules. You can read about the difference elsewhere; [this nice blog post](https://codewinsarguments.co/2016/05/01/git-submodules-vs-git-subtrees/)'s tl;dr is IMO a very good summary:

> - Is the external repository something you own yourself and are likely to push code back to? Then use a submodule. This gives you the quickest and easiest way for you to push your changes back.
> - Is the external repository third party code that you are unlikely to push anything back to? Then use a subtree. This gives the advantage of not having to give people permissions to an extra repo when you are giving them access to the code base, and also reduces the chance that someone will forget to run a git submodule update.

EDIT: I have never worked with fiori or the SAP Web IDE, and I don't know how well Git client is integrated, so YMMV.

Comment: Hi @Amadan, as per your suggestion i read about submodules as i own the repository and will be pushing code to that repository but  i saw that, to implement submodules we need git cli  primarily but in SAP WEBIDE we have a limited set of controls where everything works with button clicks in terms of git and i couldn't find anything that would allow me to implement submodules. Thank you for pointing me to submodules though.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer for "how to store multiple apps in one repo", rather a best practice not to store multiple fiori apps in one repository:

- store one app per repository (advantages in tracking history, branching, etc.)
- use intent navigation to navigate from one app to another app
- if you use ABAP frontend, you will have a BSP app per fiori app (advantages when using cache buster, etc.)
- if you use Sap cloud platform as frontend, you will have a single "HTML5 app" per Fiori App, each of them linked to a Git Repo
- if you need to reuse controls or other common parts, you still can include parts of app A in app B

Comment: Hi @iPirate, thank you for the input. I did some more research and later came to the conclusion to use a separate repository for each application.